# How to use database stored on one pc from another connected on lan

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am making a project using php and xampp .I have two machines connected on lan. On one machine database is stored and i want to access that database from other machine .How can i do that??Please help me

Comment: Try to use  the IP address of the other computer as host instead of localhost.

Comment: That's the only thing i need to do or am i supposed to do some changes in any file??Also if i am using two different operating systems , does that works in that case??

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is a little too unspecific, I don't know if your whant phpMyAdmin to connect on the other pc, oder if you like to know how you create a database connection in yout own scripts.

If you like to change phpMyadmin for connection to another Server you should edit `YOUR_INSTALL_DIR\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php`

You need to add the following lines:

```
$i++; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']     = "192.168.0.2"; // Ip adresse or DNS Name of the remote PC
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']     = 'root';    // Or any other Mysql User on the remotePc
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'YOUR_PASS'; // Passwort for the MySql User on remote PC

$cfg['DisplayServersList']      = true; // Enables e Menu for changing DB Server
```

This would add the remote PC as new server and you can change between the 2 DB Servers in phpMyAdmin.
If you like to enter the passwort an every access to phpMyAdmin add

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

And you will geht an http form for entering Passwort and username (the Usermanagement is in phpMyAdmin in the tab 'rights"

But if you simple want to replace the existing local server with the remote pc, you yust need to add the "Host", "User" and "password" section to your default config (if the are missing)

If you are using different operating systems you can use the same config for both, you yust need to check if directories are accessable with the same path (e.g. if you specify

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] "C:\windows\temp";
```

in your config.